# Meteor subscription is not stopping

Tags: meteor, subscription

I've got what should be a relatively simple issue. I set a session, then a subscribe to a collection using the string stored in the session. But when that session changes, I need to clear the subscription data and start again.

My code is as follows:

```
let subscriptionReady;
let filteredResults = [];
let rawResults = [];
let county = Session.get('county');
let type = Session.get('type');
```

This is mostly just prep work to create some empty objects to populate later. This all gets set on a click event. After we set these placeholder objects we go and subscribe by those sessions:

```
  if (county && !type) {
    return function() {
      if (subscriptionReady) {
        subscriptionReady.stop();
      }

      filteredResults = [];
      rawResults = [];

      subscriptionReady = Meteor.subscribe('resourcesearch', county, {
        onReady: () => {
          rawResults = resourceCollection.find({}, { sort: {score: -1} }).fetch();

          rawResults.forEach((result) => {
            if (result.score) {
              filteredResults.push(result);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

At the third line I run a check to see if `subscriptionReady` exists, then it will have the `stop` method available. So then I run it. But, it doesn't actually stop anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I've got it solved. The issue was the placement of the stop call. I no longer have to check if `subscriptionReady` exists, instead I stop the subscription inside of the `onReady` method:

```
    return function() {
      filteredResults = [];
      rawResults = [];

      subscriptionReady = Meteor.subscribe('resourcesearch', county, {
        onReady: () => {
          rawResults = resourceCollection.find({}, { sort: {score: -1} }).fetch();

          rawResults.forEach((result) => {
            if (result.score) {
              filteredResults.push(result);
            }
          });            

          subscriptionReady.stop();
        }
      });
```

Comment: Why do you go through all that trouble instead of fetching the right data with a method?

Comment: That's a great suggestion actually. Probably because I haven't worked in meteor in a long long time.

Comment: Actually, you the real mvp for this comment. My answer is correct, but your suggestion is better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's `.stop()` not `.stop` [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe)

Also you can probably avoid your filtering loop by including `score` in your query. Are you looking for documents where the `score` key exists `{score: {$exists: true}}` or just where it is non zero `{$score: {$ne: 0}}`?

Also you shouldn't need to clear the subscription and start again. If you make your subscription parameter `resourcesearch` a *reactive data source* then the subscription will automatically update to give you the documents you need. Starting/stopping a subscription in response to a search would be an anti-pattern.

Comment: I copied wrong, I'm actually using `stop()`. Post updated to reflect that.